# USB speaker temporarily outputs noise when connected to USB-C dock

Tags: usb, speakers, noise, docking-station

I've been using a Samsung USB sound bar on my monitor for a few years without problems, having it connected via the monitor's integrated USB hub. The driving computer is a desktop type (Z170X-Gaming 7 mainboard) running Ubuntu 20.04. Now I switched to using a USB-C docking station (Lenovo ThinkPad USB-C Dock) either connected to the PC or to my Laptop. Mouse, keyboard and speaker are now connected to the dock.

Now, when I use the desktop PC and listen to some broadcast/music, it happens irregularly (sometimes every few minutes) that the actual output is replaced by mostly noise on the speaker, usually louder than the output before. With music, it's like static noise, while during spoken language, there is still some audible "shaping", like the pauses between words.

Based on these symptoms, I am fairly sure that the issue is not directly related to electrical/analog problems (like a ground-loop as mentioned in similar threads). For me, it looks as if the synchronization of the data stream gets lost during these noise events, leading to e.g. swapping the lower and upper byte of the 16-bit audio samples. This would explain why pauses in the audio stream are still audible.

The symptoms happen with both VLC and totem. When the noise appears, I can either wait for some 10s until the audio is back to normal, or momentarily switch the audio output to some other device and immediately back.

dmesg does not show any output when the audio goes bad or back to normal. The USB speaker registers itself with a rather bogus VID/PID identification:

```
[ 1902.525096] usb 3-1.4.3: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 1902.748627] usb 3-1.4.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1234, idProduct=5678, bcdDevice= 1.10
[ 1902.748632] usb 3-1.4.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1902.748635] usb 3-1.4.3: Product: Samsung USB Device
[ 1902.748638] usb 3-1.4.3: Manufacturer: Samsung
[ 1902.829358] input: Samsung Samsung USB Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:02.0/0000:25:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.4/3-1.4.3/3-1.4.3:1.3/0003:1234:5678.0007/input/input14
[ 1902.889739] hid-generic 0003:1234:5678.0007: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [Samsung Samsung USB Device] on usb-0000:25:00.0-1.4.3/input3
```

What could I try to debug such issues? Did anyone else ever experience something similar?

Thanks. Best regards, Philipp

Comment: Can you swap OS, say to Ubuntu 18, or 19, or install Win10 on a different drive, and try? What is VID/PID of your sound device on a different system? Does the problem go away if you remove the Type-C dock?

Comment: Same odd behaviour on Ubuntu 18.04.4 live system. VID/PID still 1234.5678. No issues so far when connecting the speaker directly to the computer (with the dock only for mouse+keyboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is just another effect/bug of the mainboard. The problem occurs seemingly randomly and when unplugging and replugging the USB speakter, it usually works until the next reboot of the computer, which I now use as kind of a solution.